# Enforce pagination in graphene relay.ConnectionField

Tags: pagination, graphene-python

The `relay.ConnectionField` implementation that ships with graphene does not by default paginate queries. (The connection can optionally be paginated using "first" or "last".) That is not practical if the connection has a large number of nodes. What would be an appropriate way to enforce pagination of e.g. no more than 100 nodes at a time?

Comment: what do you mean? do you want to ask for the next two in the actual quey?

Answer (score 3):

Graphene doesn't support defaults, unfortunately. I built myself a decorator for such cases. Set `DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE` and `MAX_PAGE_SIZE` appropriately. Could be adjusted to receive those values from the decorator itself as well, but I'm using it with Django and ergo Django's settings.

```
DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 10
MAX_PAGE_SIZE = 100

def limited_pagination(func):
    '''
    Decorator for limiting the `first` and `last` pagination parameters. Uses
    DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE and MAX_PAGE_SIZE settings. Raises an exception when
    values are invalid.
    '''

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'first' in kwargs and 'last' in kwargs:
            raise RuntimeError('Use either `first` or `last`, not both.')

        for key in ('first', 'last'):
            if key in kwargs:
                try:
                    value = int(kwargs[key])
                except ValueError:
                    raise ValueError('`{}` must be an integer.'.format(key))

                if value < 0:
                    raise ValueError('`{}` must be 0 or greater.'.format(key))
                elif value > MAX_PAGE_SIZE:
                    raise ValueError(
                        '`{}` must not be greater than {}.'.format(
                            key, MAX_PAGE_SIZE
                        )
                    )

                kwargs[key] = value
                break # Break out of for loop to skip `else` branch.

        else:
            kwargs['first'] = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE

        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result

    return wrapper
```

Usage example:

```
@limited_pagination
def resolve_whatever(self, info):
    return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you have any suggestions on doing this for something like a SQLAlchemy connection? You generally don't need to define resolve_* functions at all for connections/foreign keys, and in fact doing so would be quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for solution for django, graphene-django has `RELAY_CONNECTION_ENFORCE_FIRST_OR_LAST` and `RELAY_CONNECTION_MAX_LIMIT` settings: https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/settings/#relay-connection-enforce-first-or-last. You just need to enable `RELAY_CONNECTION_ENFORCE_FIRST_OR_LAST`, and make sure to use `DjangoConnectionField` in the Query declaration.

For example:

```
# settings
GRAPHENE = {
    'RELAY_CONNECTION_ENFORCE_FIRST_OR_LAST': True,
    'RELAY_CONNECTION_MAX_LIMIT': 50,
}

# model
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

# graphql type
class CategoryType(graphene_django.DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ("id", 'name')
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)

# query
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    categories = graphene_django.DjangoConnectionField(CategoryType)

    def resolve_categories(root, info, **kwargs):
        return Category.objects.all().order_by("id")
```